# tornado after logging in not redirecting

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, tornado

A very silly problem though, should have worked but I tried the other solutions such as return statement in the end but all in vain.

Anyways this is my route :

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/login", LoginHandler),
            #(r"/logout", LogoutHandler),
            (r"/api/request/rdbms",PostRequestHandlerRDBMS),
            (r"/api/request/kafka",PostRequestHandlerKAFKA),
            (r"/api/report", PostReportHandler),
            (r"/Ramanujan/", DefaultHandler),
            (r"/web/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path":"web/static/"})
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self,handlers,static_path="web/static",template_path="web/static",login_url="/login",cookie_secret="Li_Be_B_C_N_O_F_Ne")
```

and the corresponding handlers :

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
                   'Username: <input type="text" name="username">'
                   '<br>'
                   'Password: <input type="password" name="password">'
                   '<br><br>'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
                   '</form></body></html>')
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        getusername = self.get_argument("username")
        getpassword = self.get_argument("password")
        userquery = "select username,password from Users;"
        internaldb = MySQLdb.connect(internalhost,internalusername,internalpassword,internaldbname)
        cursor = internaldb.cursor()
        cursor.execute(userquery)
        rt = cursor.fetchall()
        list_of_users = []
        for r in rt:
            user = {}
            user["username"] = username = str(r[0])
            user["password"] = password = str(r[1])
            list_of_users.append(user)
            if getpassword == password and getusername == username:
                print "[DEBUG] this happened . . ."
                self.set_secure_cookie("username", self.get_argument("username"))
                self.redirect("/Ramanujan/")
                return
            else:
                self.write('wrong credentials supplied. Retry logging in ? <a href="/login"></a> ')
                self.redirect("/login")
                return
"""
class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("username")
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("username", "/Ramanujan/"))
        return
"""
```

I have the following imported:

from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.escape
import tornado.web
import tornado.auth
```

and this is my web app :

```
tornado.web.Application.__init__(self,handlers,static_path="web/static",template_path="web/static",login_url="/login",cookie_secret="Li_Be_B_C_N_O_F_Ne")
```

What I am failing at is :

I am able to get through correct login credentials, but it doesnt redirect me and even the "/login" link is not formed in self.write()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your coroutine will always return on the first user from the DB and never check any other.

Comment: oh damn ! thank you so much. However, the problem went of when I removed @tornado.web.authenticated from that handler. Why so? Well yes this glitch I am correcting.